# zf2 do not recognize the CSS library?

Tags: css, zend-framework2

Why my zf2 do not recognize the css library?

The Firefox  console shows me this:

> GET http://localhost/pandramon/public/css/css/animate.css [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 229ms]
>   GET http://localhost/pandramon/public/css/css/font-awesome.min.css

My code:

```
<!-- Le styles -->
<?php echo $this->headLink(array('rel' => 'shortcut icon', 'type' => 'image/vnd.microsoft.icon', 'href' => $this->basePath() . '/img/favicon.ico'))
                ->prependStylesheet($this->basePath('css/animate.css'))
                ->prependStylesheet($this->basePath('css/font-awesome.min.css'))
                ->prependStylesheet($this->basePath('css/style.css'))
                ->prependStylesheet($this->basePath('css/bootstrap-theme.min.css'))
                 ->prependStylesheet($this->basePath('css/bootstrap.min.css'))
?>
```

Comment: Add `/` before css in your path like this : `->prependStylesheet($this->basePath('/css/animate.css'))`

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php 
    echo $this->headLink(
        array(
            'rel' => 'shortcut icon', 
            'type' => 'image/vnd.microsoft.icon', 
            'href' => $this->basePath() . '/img/favicon.ico')
        )
        ->prependStylesheet($this->basePath() . '/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css');

 ?>
```

Comment: Please add some description in your answer for OP ;).